# how can I run a iPad project on a iPhone or touch

Tags: iphone

I build a iPad project,i want to run the project on iPhone with auto-resize and it's run successful on iPhone 4.1 simulator,but it's always alert 'can only installed on ipads' when i run it with my iPhone,how can I run a iPad project on a iPhone or touch,what can i do?

Answer (score 2):

You should set Targeted Device Family to iPhone/iPad in your project settings.Hope it works for you..

Comment: Thanks for your answer,i have set it yet,but no effect.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt make sense to install an iPad app in iPhone at all.
iPad has its own UI controls.You can install iPhone apps to iPad is just because iPad supports all the controls that iPhone has.
Reverse is not possible.